# AVAssetWriter finishWritingWithCompletionHandler error with unknown error

Tags: ios6, avfoundation, grand-central-dispatch, avassetwriter

I have been struggling with this problem for over a week.  I hope someone sees what I'm doing wrong.  I am attempting to use the finishWritingWithCompletionHandler: method since the finishWriting method is now deprecated.  I have not had any success using the new method.  It fails with an unknown error -11800.  I can save my MOV file using the deprecated method fine, but when I create the equivalent with the new method it fails every time.

Here is my original code:

```
dispatch_async(movieWritingQueue, ^{
    if ([self.assetWriter finishWriting]) {
        self.assetWriterAudioIn = nil;
        self.assetWriterVideoIn = nil;
        //[assetWriter release];  ARC will not allow this line.
        self.assetWriter = nil;

        self.readyToRecordVideo = NO;
        self.readyToRecordAudio = NO;

        [self.delegate movieReadyToSaveForMovieProcessor:self];
    }
    else {
        [self displayError:[assetWriter error]];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self resumeCaptureSession];
        });
    }
}];
```

My new method is as follows:

```
dispatch_async(movieWritingQueue, ^{
    [self.assetWriter finishWritingWithCompletionHandler:^{
        if (self.assetWriter.status != AVAssetWriterStatusFailed && self.assetWriter.status == AVAssetWriterStatusCompleted) {
            self.assetWriterAudioIn = nil;
            self.assetWriterVideoIn = nil;
            self.assetWriter = nil;

            self.readyToRecordAudio = NO;
            self.readyToRecordVideo = NO;

            [self.delegate movieReadyToSaveForMovieProcessor:self];
        } else {
            [self displayError:self.assetWriter.error];
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [self resumeCaptureSession];
            });
        }
    }];
}];
```

I don't think I missed anything and I'm not getting much from the error it throws.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Rob

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I finally found the answer.  The `finishWritingWithCompletionHandler:` was failing because I did not run the `markAsFinished` on the `AVAssetWriterInput` objects.  Once I ran the `markAsFinished` methods **before** the `finishWritingWithCompletionHandler:`, the process was able to complete without errors.

Answer (score 11):

I had similar problem and found that the handler didn't get called because I released the `AVAssetWriter` immediately after calling `finishWritingWithCompletionHandler:`, e.g.

```
[self.assetWriter finishWritingWithCompletionHandler:^{
    ...
}]

self.assetWriter = nil;
```

To fix it, just move the releasing line to inside the completion handler:

```
[self.assetWriter finishWritingWithCompletionHandler:^{
    ...
    self.assetWriter = nil;
}]
```

Comment: As an additional element if you are using ARC and you have assetWriter as a local variable instead of a property you can declare it with __block.

Answer (score 3):

The answer was for me to remove calling `finishWritingWithCompletionHandler`. Apparently the function was already called once.